# Finding General Formula for Number of Combinations of N digit Integer Containing 1s and 2s with Specific Condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Working on formulating hashes for database, I'm stumbled at the following combinatorics (very basic skills in this field) problem:

Let say you have $10$-digit number containing all $1$s $1111111111$

Now pick randomly $1$ from any one index $(0,1,... 9)$ and replace it with $2$. So let say replace $1$ with $2$ at 8th index. Now it becomes $1111111121$

Here's now the question: find all number of combinations of 1s and 2s in this number with the following conditions:

- each combination should be greater than $1111111121$,
- and should contain $1$ at 8th index instead of $2$

Few examples: $1111111211, 1111111212, 1111112111, 1111112112, 1111112211, 1111112212, ...$

And now determine the general formula (if possible) to find all such combinations for $N$-digit integer containing 2 at $k-$th index where  $0 \le k < N$.

I can manually find each combination but it's cumbersome especially if $N$ is large. Therefore, a formula is eagerly wanted.

Anyone knowing the solving equation to this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please avoid "do my homework for me"-style questions. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: I'm very much novice in combinatorics. This problem arose in designing hashes for database. And I'm having difficulty solving it. I'd very much appreciate if someone help me on this!

Comment: Can you maybe add a paragraph to the question explaining the link to hashes? This would improve the question greatly!

Comment: I think the question is well explained. And there's no need to add paragraph to explain the link to hashes. If you didn't understand anything in question, please let me know.

Comment: The problem is not "the question is not clear", but rather "the context is not clear". As I said above, it currently looks like a homework problem. Explaining the link to hashes would provide this context.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/10513) for why context is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that as long as any of the digits in the $0$ to $k-1$ digits contain a $2$, then the number will be greater.

Moreover, once we meet this condition, we can keep the $k^\text{th}$ digit as $1$ and the $k+1$ to $N-1$ digits can be whatever they want.

There are $(N-1)-(k)=N-k-1$ digits after the $k^\text{th}$ index. Since each of these digits can either be $1$ or $2$ without any restrictions, there are $2^{N-k-1}$ ways to choose them.

For each of these different combinations of the digits after the $k^\text{th}$ digit, we must ensure that the $k$ digits before the $k^\text{th}$ index contain at least one $2$ so that the number is greater.

There are $2^k$ ways to choose these $k$ digits if we ignore all restrictions. Of all these ways, the only time when we don't have at least one $2$ is when we choose all of the digits once (which happens $1$ time).

Hence, the total number of ways to choose these $k$ digits with the restrictions is $2^k-1$.

The total number of $N$ digit numbers satisfying the conditions is then
$$2^{N-k-1}\left(2^k-1\right)$$
$$\boxed{2^{N-1}-2^{N-k-1}}$$

Just to check that we haven't missed anything, we can check that the formula indeed works at edge conditions i.e. when $k=0$ and $k=N-1$.

Comment: But the left most digit must be $1$ according to the restrictions in the problem. There are no numbers that start with $1$ that are greater than $21111111$.

Comment: My bad, my bad... It's perfectly correct and my conditions are right. Sorry to confuse you as I got confused a little for a second!

Comment: Beautifully explained solution @alan-abraham. Thank you very much. You're a legend :)